# How do I enable the debugger in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

The debug type field is greyed out as are the build buttons. I opened a folder in visual studio 2019 with my project and source code files. I have not installed any extensions yet either. I read somewhere to select a startup item but none of the items in the solution explorer are valid except for Gradebook.dll in the debug folder although that doesn't seem to do anything.

[image]

Comment: The "folder view" is very misleading, looks like you just forgot to open the project.  File > Open > Project.

Comment: In other words, you open a folder in VS, which effectively disables all relevant menu items. You have to open a project (or solution) directly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to click the run button or press F5.
If so it should prompt you to select CPU. Then, run it again and it should work.

If that doesn't work try going into "Program.cs" in the Solution Explorer and make sure the Application.Run line is there.